# Custom schema url in web browser in windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have a windows phone 7 application which has a custom schema url for an anchor tag like (href="xxx://abcd"). The  html file is located in the isolated storage and loads in a web browser control. How can I catch the click in the webbrowser_navigating event?

Comment: Does the file load automatically?

Comment: I use the webbrowser.Navigate() method to load the local html file

Comment: So exactly what do you want to do? Can you explain in detail?

Comment: @rjBombil When a user clicks on the anchor link with custom shema url like xxxx://abcd=1, I would like it to get caught in the webbrowser_navigating event as it does for any urls with http or https.Is this possible with custome schema urls?

Comment: Did you try doing it? Does it work?

Comment: @rjBombil It works only for urls with http or https

Comment: Oh ok. Let me see if I can find anything for you.